# How copy node tree in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

I need to get java code for copy node tree inside [content/dam/img.jpg and subnodes[jcr:content and metadata]] in to [etc/mynodes]

```
Source path: conten/dam/img.jp
Destin path: etc/mynodes
```

i want copy nodes :img.jpg>jcr:content>metadata

Answer (score 4):

You can use the JCR API to play with content nodes, here I have used an example with **workspace.copy** to move the **/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits** child nodes to **/etc/mynodes/test**

> workspace.copy("/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits", "/etc/mynodes/test");

```
package com.org.var.test;

import javax.jcr.Repository; 
import javax.jcr.Session; 
import javax.jcr.SimpleCredentials; 
import javax.jcr.Node; 
import javax.jcr.Workspace;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository; 

public class WorkspaceCopyTest { 

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 

try { 

//Create a connection to the CQ repository running on local host 
 Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");

   //Create a Session
   javax.jcr.Session session = repository.login( new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray())); 

   Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
    System.out.println(workspace.getName()); 
    //make sure you doesn't have test folder in /etc/mynodes/test it will create the test folder
  workspace.copy("/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits", "/etc/mynodes/test");
   System.out.println("workspace copy completed"); 

  session.logout();
  }
 catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 } 
}
```

[image: workspacecopy]

Comment: @Hanin Jazi, please accept the answer if it works. Welcome